# Any replacement of TortoiseSVN for MAC OS 10.10?

Tags: macos, svn, smartsvn

I am currently using SmartSVN for any Update on my server.

But I have worked on windows system and `Windows` have same tool named `TortoiseSVN` is there any same tool or plugin which we can use in MAC to update our files or commit our files directly through finder ?

I have seen many answer related to this but all are very old and not work in **MAC OS 10.10**.

Any New plugin or app which will provide **finder + SVN update & commit** ?

Comment: I am having same question and SNAILSvn is the best option for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SnailSVN](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/snailsvn-free-svn-client-with-finder-integration/id1063090543?mt=12) seems have Finder Integration

[SCPlugin](http://scplugin.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1525&dsMessageId=2441924) has Finder Toolbar Support. This mostly will not work. Definitely won't work on macOS 10.12

Comment: SNiailSVN is working fine  but I haven't try SCPlugin its very old library is it still working with 10.11 OS X ?